# How to fix state mapping is not a function in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently studying react native and I explore the process of rendering the api data in the list view. Right now I have already the api data however when I tried mapping the array it says.

> TypeError: this.state.readings.map is not a function. (In 'this.state.readings.map(function (value) {
> return console.log(value);
> })', 'this.state.readings.map' is undefined)

Here is the sample api:

[Sample JSON](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb2546bd)

Inside of my ComponentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
  
    fetch('http://myip:3000/api/readings/3')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({readings:JSON.stringify(data)}))
}
```

My State:

```
this.state = {
  readings:[],
}
```

My Render:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.readings);
    return (
       
        {

            this.state.readings.map(value => {
                return (
                    console.log(value)
                )
            })

        }         
    )
}
```

Comment: If you can add your example into a code sandbox, this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is using a functional component but it will be the same behavior

https://snack.expo.io/I0VJsF1z5

[image]

The problem maybe in this line
`.then(data => this.setState({readings:JSON.stringify(data)}))`

Comment: @Mohammed I use react native for this. I already try your work however it says that Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

Comment: You are right, I missed this point. try it with <Text> then, and lets see if this works

Comment: @Mohammed it says that Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component. not change

Comment: Edited, if you can share your code on this application it will be helpful https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: let me try on that.

Comment: Updated the example with the array you sent in the other comment.

Comment: Your ploblem maybe because of this line `.then(data => this.setState({readings:JSON.stringify(data)}))
` make sure it return an array

Comment: Yah question: it says after i change the code it shows another error that Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component?

Comment: Add your code on snack.expo so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

If the value of this.state.readings is `[{"id":1,"AccountNo":"011-001","ConsName":"Jenny Fox.","Address":"Pacific Triad Road."}]`.

Then this code should work.

And as your data is loading async. You can add a check for this.state.readings before mapping it.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      readings: [
        {
          id: 1,
          AccountNo: "011-001",
          ConsName: "Jenny Fox.",
          Address: "Pacific Triad Road."
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      this.state.readings.length &&
      this.state.readings.map((value) => {
        console.log(value);
        return <div>{value.Address}</div>;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

ref : https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-cdn-5695m?file=/src/App.js:51-484

Comment: @DevGe What do you want to return from the map?

Comment: Could you please show an output for your this.state.reading?

Comment: yes I want to return the all the datas in the list, however I got error TypeError: this.state.readings.map is not a function. (In 'this.state.readings.map(function (value) { return console.log(value); })', 'this.state.readings.map' is undefined)

Comment: [{"id":1,"AccountNo":"011-001","ConsName":"Jenny Fox.","Address":"Pacific Triad Road."}]

Comment: Yah question: it says after i change the code it shows another error that Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component?\